# How lsof attach to shell script PID?

Tags: linux, shell-script, lsof

I am trying to run a small shell script `.sh` and i wanted to see what files it's going to open using `lsof`. how do i execute shell script and attach its PID to `lsof`?

I tried following but didn't work:

```
lsof -p $(./foo.sh)
```

and

```
lsof -c ./foo.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

> wanted to see what files it's going to open

```
strace -f -e open bash ./foo.sh
```

Or you can run your shell in the backgroud and immediately run lsof

```
$ ./short-lived-script.sh & lsof -p $!
```

Comment: i want to see that in `lsof` i already tried strace. I want that in `lsof`

Comment: Is your script long running ?

Comment: No, its short run, 3 or 4 second